# Rotating “MoveableImageView” object wont rotate in place

Tags: ios

Im trying to add an image to a ViewController, that can be rotated.

The problem is as soon as i try to rotate the moveable object, the objects move to its initialised place, to the origin x,y and rotating over there, instead of rotating in place.
My question is how do i prevent doing so, is there a way to set the objects position as soon as the movement ends?

```
#import "MovableImageView.h"

@implementation MovableImageView

-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    self = [super initWithImage:image];
    if (self) {
        UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationGestureRecognizer= [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRotations:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:rotationGestureRecognizer];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    float deltaX = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self].x - [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self].x;
    float deltaY = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self].y - [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self].y;
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.transform, deltaX, deltaY);
}

-(void) handleRotations: (UIRotationGestureRecognizer *) paramSender
{
    self.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.rotationAngleInRadians + paramSender.rotation);
    if (paramSender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        self.rotationAngleInRadians += paramSender.rotation;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I recommend using a UIPanGestureRecognizer instead of detecting touches for movement, as it is a lot easier to handle translation. When you have the UIRotationGestureRecognizer, apply the rotation to the existing transform before reseting the gesture recognizer:

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, paramSender.rotation;
paramSender.rotation = 0;
```

This way you do not have to keep track of the rotation and you can handle movement. Again, when handling the UIPanGestureRecognizer, you can apply the translation to the existing transform:

```
-(void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)panGesture
{
    CGPoint translation = [panGesture translationInView:self];
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.transform, translation.x, translation.y);
    [panGesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self];
}
```

(To use these methods you *may* need to set self.transform to `CGAffineTransformIdentity` in your initialization method).